# swap one element list to int

Tags: python

`a = [{43:123}, {3:103}, {36:103}, {2:102}, {23:100}]`

How can I extract id from it when each of the keys is id and value means a number of points.
I tried use this:

```
for b in a: 
     print a[i].keys()
     i+=1
```

Python result is a list, but I need integer type. eg 
`print a[2].keys()` result `[36]` and I need 36 which is int. Thx

Comment: I think you mean `for item in a: print item.keys[0] `

Comment: `i+=1` -> its not c++.. no need for that

Comment: @JoelCornett No, he wants keys. Also, a is not a dict, and has no .items() method

Comment: @PraveenGollakota yes I did, I edited my previous comment :p

Comment: @JoelCornett You forgot to call the `keys` method. Use `keys()[0]`.

Comment: @HodofHod phone keyboard :p I give up!

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't a single dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the first element from such list:

```
a[2].keys()[0]
```

or

```
next(a[2].iterkeys())
```

both returning the int `36`.

To get a list of all keys:

```
[next(d.iterkeys()) for d in a]
```

returning `[43, 3, 36, 2, 23]`

Maybe you should convert your list of dicts into a simple dict:

```
d = {}
for x in a:
    d.update(x)
```

obtaining `{2: 102, 3: 103, 23: 100, 36: 103, 43: 123}`, where you can get all keys with simple `d.keys()` and obtaining `[3, 2, 43, 36, 23]`, although the order is not conserved.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [next(iter(d)) for d in a]
[43, 3, 36, 2, 23]
```

Comment: +1, I was about to say this as well. This is a very clean approach.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a list of dicts, so the `keys` method will give you the keys of the dict, and since they all have only one entry, use `[0]` to reference it:

```
>>> [d.keys()[0] for d in a]
[43, 3, 36, 2, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I responded in the comment to your other question, this is what you want:

Try:

```
for b in a: 
    print b.keys()[0]
```

that will extract the keys, so you will end up printing out: 43, 3, 36, 2, 23. If you want values instead (like 123,103,36,102,100), use `b.values()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [36] in a resulting list and you want to get to the item, simply subscript to element 0.

I.e., simply append `[0]` to your expression that got you [36] to get to the first (and only) item in your list.

So, in your case:

```
print a[2].keys()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def getKeyAtIndex(a, idx):
    return a[idx].keys()[0]
```

And call it like this:

```
print getKeyAtIndex(a, 2)
> 36
```

As a side note - this is the second question you've posted with the same data structure - a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary holds a single key with a single value. That doesn't make much sense, you're gaining nothing by using a dictionary in this case. Maybe a single dictionary would be a better idea? like this:

```
{43:123, 3:103, 36:103, 2:102, 23:100}
```

Or perhaps a list of tuples? like this:

```
[(43, 123), (3, 103), (36, 103), (2, 102), (23, 100)]
```